# How to test Webservices with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, soap, web-services, phpunit

I neet to test a couple of SOAP webservices. 
What types of tests can I run?

Comment: Stubbing and Mocking Web Services
http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

Comment: Thank you. But I was looking for functionalities to test the webservice itself and not the corresponding PHP code.

Comment: then you have to implement those webservices in PHP and call those implementation functions.

Answer (score 8):

It is by far better to test the local consumer classes with mocks of the SoapClient that return pre-recorded result XML, since Unit-Tests are meant to run fast and be independant from remote services.

- Create a Mock class of your Client class (you should have an object wrapper for the SoapClient to be able to test it thoroughly)
- Use `$this->returnValue()` to return pre-recorded XML responses or headers that your system expects

See: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

If your system is dependant on the availability of those remote services, you could implement a watchdog service that checks if the ressource is available, but this is not something that should be done in the Unit-Tests themselves.

Kind regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Testing a SOAP web-service will be quite the same than testing a "local" method : you'll have to call that method, passing it some parameters, and chechink the return value, to verify that it corresponds to the parameters you gave.

Of course, with web-services, the call will be a bit more complicated, as you'll have to work with [`SoapClient`](http://www.php.net/soapclient) to call the method, but the idea will still be the same.

The biggest problems I see are :

- Web services calls are slow *(they go though a network)*, which means your tests will take time to execute -- which means you won't be able to execute them as often
- With a webservice, you potentially have more than one possible reason for failure ; which means you'll have more troubles finding out why a test failed :

  - It can fail because there is a bug -- that's the ideal case
  - But it can also fail because the remote server is down
  - Or because the network is down
  - And probably quite some other possile reasons
- Of course, as the code will be executed on a remote server, and not on the machine that runs PHPUnit, it'll be much harder to get code-coverage *(for instance)*

Answer (score 0):

I found http://www.versioneye.com/package/fakeweb it is

> FakeWeb is a helper for faking web requests in Ruby. It works at a
>   global level, without modifying code or writing extensive stubs.